# React Fetch to Laravel API Creates New Session

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, session, fetch

My app is using React on the front end and Laravel 5.4 on the backend.  I'm using `fetch()` to request data from the backend.  The problem is that two sessions are created when the page loads. A `TokenMismatchException` is thrown by the CSRF Middleware when a `POST` request is made because the token that is sent matches the first session that is created, but it checks against the second.

I'm setting the token in `app.blade.php`

`<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

And grabbing the token in the fetch config

```
fetchConfig = {
    headers:  {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin'
}}
```

Here are the decrypted sessions:

```
a:3:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"7obvOzPaqqJDtVdij8RaqrvmTFLjKA2qnvYMxry6";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:24:"http://localhost/page";}s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}

a:3:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"5Aiws9Qy72YzlkfWX81zkhzrSeiMDYjFWiLeDAwN";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:41:"http://localhost/api/page";}s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}
```

Request URL: `http://localhost/page`

API URL: `http://localhost/api/page`

How can I prevent a new session from being created when the React app makes its initial `GET` request?

Comment: Which session driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using the `file` session driver.

Comment: If you used JWT Auth(JSON Web Token Authentication) token to Laravel API . because API cannot maintain state. So, if you need Csrf Token verification, you have to implement it storing it in a meta tag or inside a JWT payload as a private claim.

Comment: @bill did you ever figure out how to prevent multiple sessions from being created?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Laravel automatically generates a CSRF "token" for each active **user session** managed by the application. This token is used to verify that the authenticated user is the one actually making the requests to the application. : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf

APIs are stateless. There is nothing like `session` in APIs. So you shouldn't use CSRF token in API. If you check [`Kernel.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php) of laravel. You will see Tylor didn't add `VerifyCsrf` middleware in API group. Which suggest that `CSRF` is only used in the request having session i.e, stateful request. I would recommend you to use JWT based authentication system for API. For more about JWT [check here](https://jwt.io/).

You can use this laravel package for JWT : https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what is your request URL and what is your target API url. Make sure both are on same domain(including subdomain).

I think its a good idea to disable CSRF validation only for API routes as these might be used by other domains, native apps etc

You can do that by adding following class file: app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'api/*',
    ];
}
```

Make sure to edit `Kernal.php` to point to the new class:

```
protected $middleware = [
    'csrf' => 'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'
];
```

To learn more how Laravel uses CSRF check [this laracast video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/11)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I added the request and api urls to the question, as they were hidden in the session data.  Your solution works to bypass the csrf middleware, but multiple sessions are still being created.  I would ideally like to fix that if possible.