# Laravel enable csrf protection on api middleware

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I'm working on Laravel 5.4 and my routes are in the api middleware

I see that I need to transfer my routes to the web middleware, but I need them to be on the api middleware since I'm creating a RESTful api, any suggestions on how 
I could use csrf with api middleware?

Comment: What version of Laravel?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf

Comment: Which middleware group is it in?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm on Laravel 5.4

Comment: @apokryfos The api middleware

Comment: Put it in the web middleware as well (i'm assuming your main routes are part of the web group? Check `routes/web.php`) You probably just removed it from there.

Comment: @apokryfos you're actually right! but I still need them to be on the api middleware and have csrf protection

Comment: This does not make sense. Why do you need to move routes from api to web, but still have them in api? Could you tell us what you're _really_ doing?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43525110/6628079

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CSRF protection prevents attacks using a previously authenticated user (normally setting a state using session) https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF).

A restful API do not have state https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer, so there is no session to attack. So in a restful API the CSRF protection is to authenticate the user on each request, if you are only authenticating the user on the first request and use session for the following requests you are not making a restfull API and should use the web middleware.

Edit:
How are you going to get the CSRF token to the client if you don't have any state?

Comment: Yes, there is no session to attack, but the point is where do you store the token? and how do you protect it from XSS attack?

Answer (score 3):

you can use any middleware as well as your custom middleware in any route group. Laravel makes it very easy for us. Just open the `Kernel.php` file in `App\Http` namespace. Find `protected $middlewareGroups` probable on line 28 and the change the code like below to allow the enable `Csrf` protection in api routes:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: Yes, we can add middleware, but your solution raises an error saying there's no session, which is true since API's are stateless

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your web middleware group contains the following line and just be sure verify the content with a clean laravel installation of the same version.

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

And verify that the routes use the web middleware. You check that by running `php artisan route:list` and note the middleware column.

Comment: I'm on the api middleware

Comment: By default csrf is only applied to the web routes., since api don't use csrf tokens. If you forcibly want to enable csrf checks on your api then you can add `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,` to your api middleware group.

Comment: Did that, now getting a "session store not set on request" on POST -> added these " \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class," to the api middleware group too.

Comment: @kdyz I read your edit and here are my thoughts. The apis are not meant to use sessions and since the api will be usually authenticated using a token, there is no need for using csrf tokens. If the api is public without any authentication then i see no point in enforcing csrf check for those as well, since anyone can use it. Ultimately i see no valid reason for you to enforce a csrf check for an api.