# How to POST to Laravel API with CSRF Token?

Tags: php, android, laravel, rest, api

I am creating an API using laravel and I noticed that when trying to create a form for POST, I need to use csrf token. However, I will be using this API for a mobile app. How do I post to laravel with a token? Do I have to fetch it in laravel first or should I just place an exception in the middleware?

If I should be using the csrf token, does it expire? How long does it last?

Comment: You can add the API routes to the exceptions within VerifyCSRFToken.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel enable csrf protection on api middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006417/laravel-enable-csrf-protection-on-api-middleware)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use other authentication ways. OAuth, JWT... Laravel passport is a powerful way to do that. A  service for mobile app, specially mobile app, will need those authentication types. CSRF Token is working a lil bit different way