# How can I protect my Single Page Application against CSRF

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, csrf

I'm building a single page app with vue js on the frontend and laravel on the backend.

I have a couple of contact forms for guests. I made a script to make post requests with data to the laravel api endpoint.

How can I prevent this from users abusing ? Besides Google Recaptcha is there another way ?

Comment: laravel provides CSRF protection https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf

Comment: I believe that doesn't work on single-page-apps in the api routes. I only need on the API side.

Comment: I tried that. The data is being sent but not validated.

Comment: Add it on header request

Comment: I tried that . The data is being sent in the headers but not validated on the backend. CSRF is not required or possible in any of the api routes.

Comment: You can verify here too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44106621/9486728

Answer (score 2):

You don't use csrf token in single page application. You need to use a jwt auth / token, which you sent on each request. Single Page Application do not have a session like a normal Laravel application would have so.

Look at following [thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170388/do-i-need-csrf-token-if-im-using-bearer-jwt), this answer describes it good I think:

> Generally, CSRF happens when a browser automatically adds headers (i.e: Session ID within a Cookie), and then made the session authenticated. Bearer tokens, or other HTTP header based tokens that need to be added manually, would prevent you from CSRF.

Comment: As i said : I have a couple of contact forms for guests.

Comment: @bmpf_pt you still can sent form in spa if you mean that just sent using axios or the fetch api

Comment: I know. But I built a script outside the app to send post request... Somebody can explore that to spam my application.

Comment: @utdev "You don't use csrf token in single page application" Who said? JWT's typically are stored in localstorage making it possible for XSS attack to see them. A safer bet is to store the JWT in an HttpOnly cookie. If you do this, then it is advised to also have CSRF protection.